# R image() / image.plot() giving different results while drawing or exporting big matrix

Tags: r

I have a big matrix (about 150 000 rows x 4 columns) ordered by one of the columns. I wanted to make  a heat map using image() function but each time I change margin, or export resolution even by few pixels and the heat map gets redrawn it gives me drastically different results.

The code I use is:

```
    image.plot(x=c(1:4),
    y=seq(0,86945, by = 1),
    z=LEfinalMatrixT,
    col = mypalette,
    axes = F,
    ylab='',
    xlab='',
    xaxs = "i",
    yaxs="i",
    horizontal=F,
    ylim=c(0,86945),
    axis.args = list(cex.axis=1.2, at= seq(-3,1,by=1),labels = c("-3","-2","-1"," 0"," 1")),
    legend.mar = 8,breaks = seq(-4,1.5,by=0.5))
```

Here are two images exported by running above code. One in 1200x1200px and second in 1199x1201px.
I'm new here and can't post images directly to the post but here are the links:

```
    http://i62.tinypic.com/2uhv813.png
    http://i59.tinypic.com/2irtfd5.png
```

If you look closer differences are huge and may highly impact the findings. Did any of you guys had similar problem? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: From what package does your `image.plot()` come? Is it **fields::image.plot()**?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It comes from "fields" package.